# outlook 2010: is there a way to combine the navigation pane and the to-do bar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I use outlook on a tall monitor, in full screen mode. The content of my navigation pane takes about 20% of my vertical space. The content of my to-do bar takes about 60% of my vertical space. Together these bars take up 50% of my horizontal space, most of which is wasted.

Is there a way to embed the to-do bar in my navigation pane?

Comment: Haven't found a way to combine them. How about resizing to eliminate the wasted space? You can minimize them, by using the `>` at the top, when not in use?

Comment: Resizing them doesn't help, they have to be at least a certain width to even be useful. Hiding them seems like an option, but it's a bit sub-prime

Comment: Hiding them may be your only option. I have been unable to find ANYTHING to combine them. Outlook Developer forums even say it's not capable of doing it. Sorry to be a bummer.